# I have a problem in getting exact value from database by Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to search by Hibernate search and get fields of the table which fields equals to value of search parameter not like how it does search

I have a field which I search

```
@Field(name = "field", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "whitespaceAnalyzer"))
private String field;
```

and I search it by creating this query

```
queryBuilder.keyword().onField("field").matching("value").createQuery()
```

But it searches by like operator not equal
I know that if I write

```
@Field(name = "field", analyzer = Analyze.NO)
```

It will work but I want to let `@Field` annotation in this way and search field by equal operator How can I do it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of

> javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityDAO.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Field_className.class);

    Root<Field_className> entity = criteriaQuery.from(Field_className.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(entity.get("field"),identifier));
    Field_className = (Field_className)entityDAO.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Please note replace `Field_className` with your className

Comment: thank you for answer but I cannot use CriteriaBuilder in my project is there another solution or not. something set analyze == NO through FullTextEntityManager